# Is "apocrypha" plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, greek

Is "apocrypha" plural? These are extra-canonical books of the Bible. Is a singular one called an apocryphum or apocryphon or something like that?

Comment: It appears that English speakers are [hopelessly confused](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apocryphus%2Capocryphum%2Capocryphon%2C+an+apocrypha&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) as to what the singular of *apocrypha* should be. (And no, it's not *apocryphon*; that's an apocryphal plural.)

Comment: @PeterShor: Oh, I dunno, the green line seems fairly hopeful to me.

Comment: And we haven't even mentioned the difference between the Apocryphya and the Pseudepigrapha.

Comment: Try to figure it out from the [chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apocrypha%20is,apocrypha%20are&year_start=1880&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3): ![chart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eAMAV.jpg)

Comment: I think it's actually called *an apocryphal book*.

Comment: @GEdgar From this Ngram, you can't tell whether some people treat *apocrypha* as a mass noun or as a singular noun. Try looking at "an apocrypha".

Comment: @chaos: maybe you're right, and *apocryphon* is becoming the singular. But *apocryphon* and *apocryphum* are (respectively) Greek and Latin backformations from the noun *apocrypha*, which was originally a Latin adjective, but which turned into an English plural noun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a plural.  The singular is [apocryphon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocryphon) (it's Greek).

Answer (score 2):

Merriam-Webster labels *[apocrypha](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apocrypha)* as:

> noun pl(ural) but singular or pl(ural) in constr(uction)

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Good copy and paste answer, but what does "but singular or pl(ural) in constr(uction)" mean? Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh sorry, when I refreshed the page saw the PS's answer.

Comment: I think it means that if you have to make it singular, you should use *apocrypha*.

Comment: @PeterShor - Really?

Comment: @Carlo_R. thanks; that means a lot coming from you.

Comment: Actually, my personal feeling is that *apocrypha* can be treated either as a plural noun or as a mass noun, but not as a count noun. So you can say *apocrypha is* but not *an apocrypha*. This [seems to be](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apocrypha+is%2Capocrypha+are%2Cthe+apocrypha+is%2Can+apocrypha+is%2Cthe+apocrypha+are&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=20) borne out by Google Ngrams.